# Sorting an array by its values based on two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexing

I currently have 2 arrays, power and energy:

```
int[] power = [20, 10, 50, 10, 30, 5];
powerIndex     0   1   2   3   4   5
int[] energy = [20, 5, 15, 3, 10, 30];
energyIndex    0   1   2   3   4   5
```

I would like get an array with the indices of the power array sorted (lowest to highest), and in case the power number is the same, the power that uses less energy should get the first spot. So basically my desired output would be:

```
int[] result = [5, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2]
```

This is my code so far:

```
        int[] result = new int[power.length];
        int answerIndex = 0;
        int tempSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int lastNumberSaved = 0;
        int posWithSmallerPower = 0;


        while (answerIndex < power.length) {

            for (int i = 0; i < power.length; i++) {
                int current = power[i];
                if (tempSmallest > current && current > lastNumberSaved) {
                    tempSmallest = current;
                    posWithSmallerPower = i;
                }

                if (tempSmallest >= current && current > lastNumberSaved) {
                    if (current != lastNumberSaved && energy[posWithSmallerPower] > energy[i]) {
                        tempSmallest = current;
                        posWithSmallerPower = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            answer[answerIndex] = posWithSmallerPower;
            answerIndex++;
            lastNumberSaved = tempSmallest;
            tempSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        return answer;
```

What i'm getting: [5, 3, 0, 4, 2, 2].
And again, what I'm supposed to get: [5, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2]

I'm having trouble dealing with the powers that have the same number. I do compare them in the second array by their energy and I actually get the power in the index 3 first, but then the code completely forgots about the second power that also had the same number (10).

How do I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a college homework. There is no problem with your code. You need to think what you are trying to achieve. Sketch it up in a piece of paper and then start coding.

Comment: @brainless-coder Thank you! I made this post after about 5-6 hours of exactly doing that. I completely refused to ask for help until I just got really tired of trying countless "solutions" that came to mind and seemed to push me away from the result even more. I do appreciate your intentions tho, peace!

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good use case for a temporary data structure that implements the `Comparable` interface. The [javadoc for `Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) explains how this works pretty well but this is an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class Main {

    private static class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
        private final int power;
        private final int energy;
        private final int index;

        public Entry(int power, int energy, int index) {
            this.power = power;
            this.energy = energy;
            this.index = index;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Entry o) {
            if (this.power != o.power) {
                return this.power - o.power;
            }
            return this.energy - o.energy;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] power = {20, 10, 50, 10, 30, 5};
        int[] energy = {20, 5, 15, 3, 10, 30};

        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < power.length; i++) {
            entries.add(new Entry(power[i], energy[i], i));
        }

        Collections.sort(entries);
        List<Integer> result = entries.stream()
                .map(entry -> entry.index)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[5, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Used an inline `Comparator<T>` in `list.sort()` to compare the two powerEnergyIndex.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] power = {20, 10, 50, 10, 30, 5};

        int[] energy = {20, 5, 15, 3, 10, 30};

        List<PowerEnergyIndex> powerEnergyIndices = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<power.length;i++) {
            powerEnergyIndices.add(new PowerEnergyIndex(power[i],energy[i],i));
        }

        powerEnergyIndices.sort((p1, p2)-> {
            if(p1.power!=p2.power) {
                return p1.power-p2.power;
            }
            return p1.energy-p2.energy;
        });

        int[] result = powerEnergyIndices.stream()
                                            .map(powerEnergyIndex -> powerEnergyIndex.index)
                                            .mapToInt(x->x)
                                            .toArray();

        for(int i:result) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }



    }

    static class PowerEnergyIndex {
        private int power;
        private int energy;
        private int index;

        public PowerEnergyIndex(final int power, final int energy, final int index) {
            this.power = power;
            this.energy = energy;
            this.index = index;
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs
`5 3 1 0 4 2`